# Reading System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StandardOutput as bytes instead of chars

Tags: c#, .net, svn

I'm trying to automate svnadmin dump using C# ProcessStartInfo.

The way I've done it on the command line is like so,

`svnadmin dump c:\Repositories\hackyhacky > c:\backup\hackyhacky.svn_dump`

Works a treat and dumps successfully, and I can verify this by restoring it into another repository like so

`svnadmin load c:\Repositories\restore_test < c:\backup\hackyhacky.svn_dump`

Which restores successfully - yay!

Now... I need to replicate the command line piping into another file using C#, but for some reason

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(SvnPath, "svnadmin"),"dump c:\Repositories\hackyhacky")
 {CreateNoWindow = true, RedirectStandardOutput = true,RedirectStandardError = true,UseShellExecute = false};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
char[] standardOutputCharBuffer = new char[4096];
byte[] standardOutputByteBuffer;
int readChars = 0;
long totalReadBytes = 0;

// read from the StandardOutput, and write directly into another file

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\backup\hackyhacky.svn_dump", false)) {
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
       // read some chars from the standard out
       readChars = reader.Read(standardOutputCharBuffer, 0, standardOutputCharBuffer.Length);

       // convert the chars into bytes
       standardOutputByteBuffer = reader.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(standardOutputCharBuffer);

       // write the bytes out into the file
       writer.Write(standardOutputCharBuffer.Take(readChars).ToArray());

       // increment the total read
       totalReadBytes += standardOutputByteBuffer.Length;
    }                    
}
```

Dumps the same repo into hackyhacky.svn_dump.

But when I run my load command line now

`svnadmin load c:\Repositories\restore_test < c:\backup\hackyhacky.svn_dump`

I get a checksum error weird-error!

```
svnadmin load c:\Repositories\restore_test < c:\backup\hackyhacky.svn_dump
< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
     * adding path : Dependencies ... done.
     * adding path : Dependencies/BlogML.dll ...svnadmin: Checksum mismatch, fil
e '/Dependencies/BlogML.dll':
   expected:  d39863a4c14cf053d01f636002842bf9
     actual:  d19831be151d33650b3312a288aecadd
```

I'm guessing this is to do with how I'm redirecting and reading the StandardOutput.

Does anyone know the right way to mimic the command line file piping behaviour in C#?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-CV

**UPDATE**

I've tried using a BinaryWriter and using the standardOutputByteBuffer to write to the file, but that doesn't work either. I get a different error about incorrect header format or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! If you can't beat em, join em....

I found a post where the author pipes to a file directly within the Process StartInfo, and claims it works.

http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2004/08/31/223447.aspx

It didn't work for me, as described in another gentleman's post

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.deadbeef.com/index.php/redirecting_the_output_of_a_program_to_a

He writes a batch file first with the piping and then executes it...

```
amWriter bat = File.CreateText("foo.bat"); 
bat.WriteLine("@echo off"); 
bat.WriteLine("foo.exe -arg >" + dumpDir + "\\foo_arg.txt"); 
bat.Close(); 
Process task = new Process(); 
task.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
task.StartInfo.FileName = "foo.bat"; 
task.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; 
task.Start(); 
task.WaitForExit();
```

In his words:

> Truly horrific, but it has the
>   advantage of working!

To be perfectly frank, I'm a bit annoyed this has taken me as long as it has, so the batch file solution works well so I'm going to stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd try is writing the character array - not the byte array - to the file.

That should work as long as the output is just simple text. There's other encoding issues, though, if the output is more complex: you're writing the file as UTF-8, whereas the default for command-line output (I believe) is Windows-1252.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I am in the current code there writing the char array. I tried both switching the chars into bytes and writing those too. Both approaches don't work, and produce different errors

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this very thing, and just stumbled on another [solution](http://www.systemwidgets.com/DesktopModules/DnnForge%20-%20NewsArticles/Print.aspx?tabid=53&tabmoduleid=60&articleId=38&moduleId=371&PortalID=0) to the problem used by [Hector Sosa's](http://sourceforge.net/users/hectorsosa) [svnmanagerlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnmanagerlib/) sourceforge project:

> The key to solving this was surrounding the call to WaitForExit() with
>   file operations. Also needed to make sure to write the output to disk.
>   Here are the relevant lines:
>
> File.AppendAllText( destinationFile, myOutput.ReadToEnd() );
>   svnCommand.WaitForExit(); File.AppendAllText(destinationFile,
>   myOutput.ReadToEnd() );
>
> Notice that I make a call to File.AppendAllText() twice. I have found
>   that the output stream does not write everything during the first call
>   to File.AppendAllText() on some occasions.

```
public static bool ExecuteWritesToDiskSvnCommand(string command, string arguments, string destinationFile, out string errors)
        {
            bool retval = false;
            string errorLines = string.Empty;
            Process svnCommand = null;
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(command);

            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

            try
            {
                Process.Start(psi);
                psi.Arguments = arguments;
                svnCommand = Process.Start(psi);

                StreamReader myOutput = svnCommand.StandardOutput;
                StreamReader myErrors = svnCommand.StandardError;

                File.AppendAllText(destinationFile, myOutput.ReadToEnd());
                svnCommand.WaitForExit();
                File.AppendAllText(destinationFile, myOutput.ReadToEnd());

                if (svnCommand.HasExited)
                {
                    errorLines = myErrors.ReadToEnd();
                }

                // Check for errors
                if (errorLines.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    retval = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
                errorLines += Environment.NewLine + msg;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (svnCommand != null)
                {
                    svnCommand.Close();
                }
            }

            errors = errorLines;

            return retval;
        }
```